# Visual Studio Deployment -IIS

Tags: visual-studio

I have a web application created in visual studio. I wish to deploy it as an intranet -IIS. How to proceed?

Comment: What have you tried? You haven't provided any information at all. As the question currently stands I have at least 1,000 questions.

Comment: Proceed by reading tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

here is full tutorial to do this :

[ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis)

here is deployment through Azure :

[ASP.NET MVC - Deployment](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_mvc/asp.net_mvc_deployment.htm)